# Laravel Query is not working as aspected on multiple where and orWhere?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a data having table name `users` that has fields of `id, role_id, first_name, last_name, name, and email`. What I trying to get is the `role_id of 2 with any match from the name, first_name, or last_name.`

`Laravel Framework 8.77.1` 
`PHP 7.4.3`

The database table is
[image]

What I am trying is the `Laravel Query`

```
public function search_friend_custom(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->input('search');
    $search = 'chase '; 
    // ** $Search variable has chase string for searching.**

    $friends = DB::table('users')
            
            ->select('users.*','users.id as user_tab_id')

            ->where('role_id', 2)
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')

            ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    
            ->paginate(10); 

    return view('user.custom_search' , compact('friends'));

}
```

What it is returing are both Chase's Hadyman Services with role_id=3 and Chase Mary role_id=2 both. But `the aspected result is only Chase Mary as it's role_id is 2`.

Please guide, I am not getting what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should logically group them inside a closure so your `role_id` takes precedence but doesn't interfere with the rest of the query.

```
$friends = DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.*','users.id as user_tab_id')
    ->where('role_id', 2)
    ->where(fn($builder) => $builder->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
    )->paginate(10);
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping) for more references.

Comment: It fixed the issue, Thank you so much, you saved my day. Please elaborate the `fn(builder)`. #Jaquarh

Comment: `arrow functions` were introduced in PHP 7.4, you can find [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) on them if you want to do some further reading

Comment: You may want to replace `'%' . $search . '%'` with `'%{$search}%"`

Comment: For readability, I normally do but truthly, I just copied and pasted from the OP since logical grouping is already well documented in Laravel. If the OP wants to do further research on escaping with double quotes, then there are the PHP docs for that. Technically it should have been done once: at the declaration of `$search`. @MarcinOrlowski